# How to change the first letter of the column name to upper case in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I need to change the first letter of all column names to upper case. Is there a quick way to do it? I've found only rename() and prefix() functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.columns` (like in pandas):

```py
df.columns = [col.capitalize() for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution, which doesn't involve assigning to a property:

```py
df = df.rename({col: col.capitalize() for col in df.columns})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another one:

```
df.select(
    pl.all().map_alias(lambda colName: colName.capitalize())
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).